# How can I have multiple text entry variables?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having a problem in python where I am making a username/password system but I can't havbe multiple variables for the input in the entry boxes.

Here is the problem:

```
mEntry1 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = ment).grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = W)
mEntry2 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = ment).grid(column = 0, row = 4, sticky = W)
```

The entry boxes always have the same writing in and I can't change ment or textvariable otherwise I get errors. How do I assign inputs to different variables?

Comment: Do you really need to use textvariables, or do you only think you need to? It's pretty normal to _not_ use textvariables unless you need their special behaviors (such as tracing, or tying two widgets together)

Answer (score 4):

Two problems:

- if you assign a widget and `grid` it on the same line, the variable will be `None`, because that's what `grid` returns. Assign and grid on separate lines.
- Each entry should have a separate textvariable.

```
mEntry1 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = ment1)
mEntry2 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = ment2)
mEntry1.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = W)
mEntry2.grid(column = 0, row = 4, sticky = W)
```

---

Bonus style tip: try to pick variable names that reflect the purpose of the UI elements. Ex:

```
username_entry = Entry(mGui, textvariable = username_var)
password_entry = Entry(mGui, textvariable = password_var)
username_entry.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = W)
password_entry.grid(column = 0, row = 4, sticky = W)
```

This will make it easier to identify which variables do what. When you come back in six months to add new functionality, you'll thank your past self for making things understandable.

Comment: Thank you for the help on the grid part and variable naming but I still have a problem: For username_var is came up with an error saying "username_var" is not defined. I called a function that gets the username_var from the entry, here is part of it and this is the error:
    `def mfetchinfo():
        mtext1 = username_var.get()`

Comment: If you're creating `username_var` in one function and trying to access it in another function, it won't be visible; only the first function can see the variable. You could make `username_var` a global variable; or you could create it outside of any function so it's visible anywhere; or you could refactor your program so all the GUI stuff is in one `MyApplication` class, and then all methods of that class can share variables like `self.username_var`.

Comment: I tried making them global variables but it still did not work, and I am not experienced enough to create the class.

Comment: Please respond, text is aslo appearing in both boxes when typing in one.

Comment: No, global variables should work. There must be a problem in the code that you haven't shared.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you are using the same variable for both entries, so when you write in one you get it in the other. You should create a second variable:

```
 ment1=StringVar()
 ment2=StringVar()
 mEntry1 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = ment1).grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = W)
 mEntry2 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = ment2).grid(column = 0, row = 4, sticky = W)
```